# Javafx jnlp deployment resources url error

Tags: jnlp

I am deploying a javafx project build using Eclipse Mars and JDK 1.8.0_66 after building and creating the project I moved the created deployments files to the server these include the application jar and jnlp file and html file and the lib directory and web-files directory, I tray to run the javafx as applet I get the following error :

```
ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable To Load ressource : http://localhost/live/lib\commons-io-2.4.jar
```

And :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost/live/lib\commons-io-2.4.jar
```

The URL to the resource in the JNLP  :

```
 <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Dprism.order=sw -Dprism.verbose=true "  href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="test.jar" size="5646452" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib\commons-io-2.4.jar" size="188207" download="eager" />
  </resources>
```

The resource URL to lib\commons-io-2.4.jar contain different slashes???? so any idea what could cause this error??

Comment: No one face such a problem other than me??? strange maybe a BUG in JDK??

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue. Using below plugin to bundle jnlp fixed it.

---

```
<groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
<artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>8.3.0</version>
```

---

Looks like oracle-jdk-bug since 1.8.0u60 itself
 [github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/182](http://%20github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/182)